# Issue With Enabling ARC in COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

im following steps from

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23854/arc-and-cocos2d-v2-x

i can not set `-fno-objc-arc` for ccCArray.h ... even if i have set -fno-objc-arc to that file , compiler gives warnings and errors related to ARC... like

```
[WARN]warning: no rule to process file 'libs/cocos2d/Support/ccCArray.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
```

what's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a header file, and no header files should be compiled. You normally include <file>.h inside your <file>.m.

To fix this, click on your project in Xcode, select your target and then check that this file is not present in the **Build Phases** tab.
Also make sure you don't have any other <file>.h in there.

Clean and build the project.